# How to add multiple images into custom post in wordpress for portfolio detail page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display multiple images into my portfolio detail page which is created using custom post type 
how to do it please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [Advanced custom fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

Use the repeater field for image and select the custom post type you need to show this repeater field.

then use `get_post_meta()` to get all the images.

Comment: can i use custom fields suit plugin for this ?

Comment: Yes if you will use this plugin then you need to create 5-10 custom image fields. I think this plugin doens't provide repeater field support.

Comment: Yes it contains repeater field.You can use repeater field and create image sub field inside the repeater. Then fetch it to front side.

Comment: can you provide me i can create any reference link of use of acf plugin ?

Comment: This is the repeater field plugin that you need to install after ACF installation.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-field-repeater-collapser/

Check the documentation of repeater field here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

Comment: how to create Slider using ACF can you please guide me for this ?

Comment: I can guide you , but just look at this articles : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/carousel-slider-implementation/

They have easy to read information for implement the slider using acf. After that if you face any issue then contact me here.

Comment: i can check it but it should provided ACF pro version which should be not free   normal ACF plugin can not provide repitar or gallery option in  Field Types

Comment: ACF PRO is needed for the repeater field btw. But luckily their license is very affordable if you ask me.